# Fundamental theorem of calculus in higher dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, manifolds, lebesgue-integral

I would like to make this statement rigorous:

I have a smooth function $E:(a,b)^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and

I would like to prove that $\int_{\{(a,b); E(a,b)<k\}}1 dx$ is differentiable as a function of $k$ if $E^{-1}(k)$ contains only regular points, then:

$\frac{d}{dk}\left(\int_{\{(a,b); E(a,b)<k\}}1 dx\right) = \int_{E^{-1}(k)} \frac{1}{|\nabla E(x)|} dS(x).$

If you can only show it under weaker /additional assumptions, then this is also perfectly fine.

This is a sort of higher-dimensional variant of $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x F(s)ds= F(x).$

Comment: Some thoughts, though not very rigorous. Let $F(k)$ be the integral in question. Then $F'(k)$ can be obtained as the limit as $h\to 0$ of $\frac1h(F(k+h)-F(k))$, and that difference can be understood as the integral over the region $k<E(a,b)<k+h.$ In the limit, one "should" end up with a integral over the surface $E(a,b)=k.$

Comment: @Semiclassical yes, it is some variant of the fundamental theorem

Comment: I usually find the integral form of this sort of thing easier to work with: showing that $$\int_{E < a} 1 \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^a \int_{E = k} 1 \mathrm{d}x  $$ and split $\mathrm{d}x$ into $f \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}k$ for some suitable $f$ and $y$.